# How to read text from Uri and put in textView? Android Studio - Java

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display text in a TextView. I have a .txt stored in Firebase Storage. I have the Url of this .txt stored in a .xml in my Android Studio project (main/res/raw)

Here is some code from onCreate in the activity.

```
str = poi.getText();
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.TEXT_STATUS_ID);
textView.setText((CharSequence) uri);
```

However I am getting problems:

```
Process: com.example.project, PID: 10040
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.project/com.example.project.POIPresentationActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$StringUri cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$StringUri cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
    at com.example.project.POIPresentationActivity.onCreate(POIPresentationActivity.java:117)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6958)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

It looks like I cannot cast the Uri to a CharSequence. What is the best way to achieve what I want to do? My method works for image, audio and video (because the cast is not necessary)

```
 str = poi.getVideoLink();
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(str);
 VideoView video = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
 video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
 video.setVideoURI(uri);
 video.requestFocus();
```

I have seen some documentation on inputStreams, but am not sure if this is the way to go. Any insight appreciated

Using the suggested toString() method does not work as intended:

```
 textView.setText((CharSequence) uri);
```

Changed to

```
 textView.setText(uri.toString());
```

Displays the text, but it displays the link of the text I want to display (https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ ...... ) - not the text contained within the .txt the link points to

Comment: use `toString()` instead

Comment: please see updated question thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)) :

```
setText (CharSequence text)
```

So it accepts a `CharSequence` as parameter but `Uri` is not!

So change to `toString()` that returns the encoded string representation of this URI.

---

Based on your update,  you want the text that is within the `.txt` file.

So first you need to create a reference of that `.txt` file (that depends on on how you stored the file [look here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/create-reference))

and pass the above `uri` like this:

```
StorageReference httpsReference = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(uri);
```

**Note** that `uri` should contain a complete address to the file, for example:

```
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/..../yourTextFile.txt"
```

Also note that if the `str` contains the `URL`, you don't then really need to use the `uri` so immediately pass `str` to the reference!

Then download the `.txt` file in the memory like this:

```
final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024; // or to the maximum size of your text, but careful it crashes if it's too big
httpsReference.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
        // String s = new String(bytes); should contain the text
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Comment: getText() returns a str of the link to the .txt, not the text within the .txt at that link. This is my problem - I want the text within the .txt file, not the link to it

Comment: thank you appreciated. Like I said I think it involves input streams. I did not have this problem with video for example because a VideoView already has a method called VideoView.setVideoURI(uri)